# How to calculate hours on certain day, based on timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table in my database with the user sessions. There are two columns called `started_at` and `ended_at`. They both contain a timestamp. Now, what I need to do is calculate the amount of hours for a given day of the week. So eventually, I need to return that of all of the sessions 350 hours took place on a monday en 250 hours took place on a tuesday and so on.

I tried doing that with the code below.

```
$day = 0;
$dayTofetch = "mon";
$sessions = Session::whereRaw('WEEKDAY(sessions.started_at) = '.$dayTofetch)->get();

foreach($sessions as $session) {
    $started_at_date = new DateTime($session->started_at);
    $ended_at_date = new DateTime($session->ended_at);

    $diff = $date2->diff($date1);
    $day = $day + $diff->format('%h');
}
```

This works, but it takes quite a lot of time to calculate this. Is there a more efficient or easier way to do this?

Comment: How many records are you returning on average?

Comment: this can probably be achieved directly with SQL

Comment: @Spholt A few hundred. I'd say on average about 250 records.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

With Carbon :

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$started_at_date = new Carbon($session->started_at);
$ended_at_date = new Carbon($session->ended_at);

$diff = $started_at_date->diffInHours($ended_at_date);
```

Comment: Is this that much quicker?

Comment: Try this and check

Comment: This is how I would do it!

Comment: Also, if your Session model has the appropriate datatypes in the migrations, or you have set casts in your model, the result of your get() will have ```started_at``` and ```ended_at``` already as Carbon instances, so this solution may be converting Carbon instances to Carbon instances adding overhead. ie) you may just be able to do, ```$session->started_at->diffInHours($session->ended_at)```

Comment: @Kurt Friars, then it can do by more easily `$diff = $session->started_at->diffInHours($session->ended_at);`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care that a session of monday 11pm- tuesday 1am is counted as 2 total hours for monday :

```
   select 
   SUM( CASE WHEN date_format(started_at,'%W') = 'Monday' THEN time_to_sec( TIMEDIFF( ended_at, started_at  ) / (60 * 60) ELSE 0 END) as monday_hours,
   SUM( CASE WHEN date_format(started_at,'%W') = 'Tuesday' THEN time_to_sec( TIMEDIFF( ended_at, started_at  ) / (60 * 60) ELSE 0 END) as tuesday_hours,
   etc
   from your_table
   where user_id = 'userX'
```